# How to get multiple versions of a column in hbase using drill

Tags: hbase, apache-drill

Hi I am wondering how to get multiple versions[Timestamps?] of a column in hbase using drill.

In hbase I am able to achieve this using

```
get 'logData','rpm1472191794',{COLUMNS => ['derivatives','readings'],VERSIONS => 10}
```

I am not able to get all the versions of the column in drill, and my research haven't given me any positive result.

```
select * from hbase.`logData`;
```

Gives me only the latest version of the data.

Can somebody help me with this. I am new to drill and hbase, but I have done my share of research.